# couldn't find dependency [hogman_minimal] of [rgbdslam]

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install rgbdslam(http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) and let it work.

When I execute *rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam*, it has error message as follows:

---

cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..

[rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam

Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests rgbdslam

[rospack] couldn't find dependency [hogman_minimal] of [rgbdslam]

[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'rgbdslam'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)

CMakeLists.txt:31 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

How can I solve it? Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12417/couldn%27t-find-dependency-%5Bhogman_minimal%5D-of-%5Brgbdslam%5D/) by [Ting](https://answers.ros.org/users/1445/ting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to install the `hogman_minimal` package. Use this command:

```
svn checkout http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/hogman_minimal
```

This can be found in the rgbdslam [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM).

**EDIT**: Run the following commands.

```
roscd hogman_minimal
rosmake
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2